# unable to install anything on ubuntu 14.10 with apt-get says files list file for package 'libgnutls-deb0-28:amd64' is missing final newline

Tags: apt, dpkg, 14.10

when I try to install anything with apt-get its showing same error for all 
I just installed, nothing yet install yet

```
user@system:~$ sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  git-man liberror-perl
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk
  gitweb git-arch git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git git-man liberror-perl
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,019 kB of archives.
After this operation, 22.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package liberror-perl.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libgnutls-deb0-28:amd64' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
user@system:~$
```

tried to purge that package its returned

```
    sudo apt-get purge libgnutls-deb0-28 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-icon-theme : Depends: libgtk-3-bin
                    Depends: humanity-icon-theme but it is not going to be installed or
                             gnome-icon-theme-full but it is not going to be installed
 hud : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 ibus : Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (>= 3.8.5) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: python-notify but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.5-4) but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: ibus-gtk but it is not going to be installed or
                    ibus-qt4 but it is not going to be installed or
                    libqt5gui5 but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: ibus-gtk3 but it is not going to be installed or
                    ibus-qt4 but it is not going to be installed or
                    libqt5gui5 but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed
 libcups2 : Depends: libgnutls-deb0-28 (>= 3.2.10-0) but it is not going to be installed
 libcurl3-gnutls : Depends: libgnutls-deb0-28 (>= 3.2.10-0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: librtmp1 (>= 2.4+20131018.git79459a2-3~) but it is not going to be installed
 libonline-accounts-client1 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                       libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libpoppler-qt5-1 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                             libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libqmenumodel0 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                           libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5multimedia5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                              libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5multimediawidgets5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5opengl5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                          libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5quick5-gles : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                              libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5svg5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                       libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5widgets5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                           libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libsoup2.4-1 : Depends: glib-networking (>= 2.32.0) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-qtmultimedia : Depends: libqt5multimedia5-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                    libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libqt5multimediaquick-p5 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-qtorganizer : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                   libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                       libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-qtquick-layouts : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                       libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-qtquick-particles2 : Depends: libqt5quickparticles5 (>= 5.2.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                                          libqt5quickparticles5-gles (>= 5.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                              libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 qtcontact5-galera : Depends: address-book-service (= 0.1.1+14.10.20140930-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 qtdeclarative5-qtlocation-plugin : Depends: libqt5location5-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: libqt53d5 (>= 5.0~git20130731) but it is not going to be installed or
                                             libqt53d5-gles (>= 5.0~git20130731) but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                             libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: libqt5location5 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                             libqt5location5-gles (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 qtdeclarative5-qtmir-plugin : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                        libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: qtmir-desktop but it is not going to be installed or
                                        qtmir-android but it is not going to be installed
 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                           libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-telephony0.1 : Depends: telephony-service (>= 0.1+14.10.20141007.1-0ubuntu1)
 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                                    libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 signon-ui : Depends: signon-ui-x11 but it is not going to be installed or
                      ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts (>= 0.4) but it is not going to be installed
 system-config-printer-gnome : Depends: system-config-printer-common (>= 1.3.11+20120807-0ubuntu7) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: python3-pycurl but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-mediascanner2 : Depends: libnet-cpp1 (>= 1.1.0+14.10.20140804) but it is not going to be installed
 unity8 : Depends: unity8-common (= 8.00+14.10.20141013.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                   libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: unity-scope-click but it is not going to be installed
 unity8-private : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                           libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libusermetricsoutput1 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I'm newbie to ubuntu so I unable to understand exactly what to do with it

Comment: Have you tried apt-get clean, and then having the package redownloaded?

Comment: I tried it but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try fixing packages with the following commands

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

UPDATE : try this `sudo apt-get -f install`

the APT will try to download and install missing packages to resolve dependencies

did you see this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: tried it, still same error

Comment: did you try to remove the affected package `sudo apt-get purge libgnutls`

Comment: updated answer with your suggestion. output is in answer, I have no idea what to do with that @younes

Comment: I searched for that package info its security package. I think its not easy to remove without solving dependencies

Comment: did you install some packages manually, i mean from source

Comment: no nothing I'm just installed ubuntu, and chrome and tried to install git that it

Comment: I tried everything from referenced question but dint worked, so I simply reinstalled the ubuntu now its working

Comment: I'm glad you have a working system, though i would like if i could know the causes so you don't encounter the same issue later

Comment: I think it is related something with bad cluster or sector disk problem which causing some error, but it only my guess

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

<s>sudo apt-get -f update</s>

**Update:**

My bad! I meant for you to try this: `sudo apt-get -f install`

The idea was to let `apt-get` get a chance to try fixing the system, if possible.  But looks like, you have tried it and that didn't solve the problem. What repositories are enabled ?

Also, have you tried removing the package that has issue?  I would try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge libgnutls-openssl27:amd64
```

Comment: yep I tried it already but didn't worked

Comment: update, upgrade, all theme commands working fine without errors but when we try to install anything its throwing errors

Comment: E: Command line option 'f' [from -f] is not known.

Comment: That's not even a valid command and even if, please explain what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I corrected the misleading information. Thanks!